# Build failed. Cannot find module 'unzip'

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am suddenly getting an error
Build failed. Cannot find module 'unzip' 
when trying to build an existing nativescript app as well as any newly created apps.
Has anyone experienced this, I have tried uninstalling sidekick and recreating it.

Comment: How are you attempting to use `unzip`? Which package is it included in? Does this package still exist in your `package.json`?

Comment: Can you post the plugin details which you are trying to use.

Comment: I am not using anything even a brand new blank project throws the error